# The resource cannot be found iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I built a website with vs 2010 with net 4.0, after publishing website into localhost (iis) on my computer, the website starts normally, but after hosting website via remote hosting, it says:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>
> Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /index.aspx

here is my web.config

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-AutoStart" value="true"/>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Sleep" value="60000"/>
<add key="CrystalImageCleaner-Age" value="120000"/>
</appSettings>
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="koneksi" connectionString="server=85.10.205.173;user    id=dataponpes;password=iwakayam;port=3306;database=ponpes"/>
</connectionStrings>
<location path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd">
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime
    executionTimeout="999999"
    maxRequestLength="2000000000"
    useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false"
    minFreeThreads="8"
    minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4"
    appRequestQueueLimit="100"
    enableVersionHeader="true"
    />
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2000000000"></requestLimits>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
</location>
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler" verb="*" validate="false"/>
  <add path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource" verb="*" validate="false"/>
  <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
</httpHandlers>
<compilation debug="true">
    <assemblies>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
    <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
  </assemblies>
  </compilation>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<handlers>
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_DialogHandler_aspx" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler.aspx" type="Telerik.Web.UI.DialogHandler"/>
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_SpellCheckHandler_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.SpellCheckHandler"/>
  <add name="Telerik_Web_UI_WebResource_axd" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" path="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd" type="Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource"/>
  <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
</handlers>
<defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.aspx" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: you need to ensure that the virtual path's are set as expected in the host IIS server etc. Do you have access to the other IIS Server? can you browse to the page from within iis

Comment: i cant access iis from somee.com, but previously i host website with vs 2012 and somee.com too, my website start normaly, here my website, ponpeszamzam.somee.com , that say error, but if i add ponpeszamzam.somee.com/index.html, it normal, all aspx index,about etc is error